# SSL error setting up tables in stellar_bridge database

Tags: bridge-server

I'm trying to start the Stellar Bridge server for the first time.  So far I've created the empty stellar_bridge database and downloaded the latest bridge server version, but when I run `./bridge --migrate-db` I am getting the following error:

> FATA[0000] Cannot connect to a DB: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server

I've tried manually disabling SSL by adding `?sslmode=disable` to the URL, but this had the same result.

I'm on a Mac with postgresql 10.5.